# How should I handle Facebook logins in my API [CakePHP 3]

Tags: php, facebook, api, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an API with CakePHP and I want to handle login with Facebook, how should I go about this? I though about just creating a new user like usual with the information Facebook gives, but is there something else I can do? Users have to use a token generated by my app to make requests to my API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this plugin https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth. It makes Facebook login super easy to integrate.